# Chromecast Custom Receiver show different content

Tags: chromecast

Is there a way for a Chromecast Customer Receiver app to differentiate which Chromecast device is connected and then show different content based on such ID or unique connector?

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking whether there is an api on the receiver side to return a unique id, the answer is no, there is no such api.